# check to see if a login exists in sql from c#

Tags: c#, sql

Within a class I am creating log-ins into sql which works fine. I wanted to add a little error checking to first check to see if the login already existing in SQL. If it does then don't try to add the login but map to the tables etc.

In sql I check for login using the following:

```
select name from sys.server_principals where name = 'viewer2'
```

I tired to use this in my class as follows

```
protected static bool CheckForExistingUser(DbContext context, string userName)
        {
            string checkForUser =
                @" SET NOCOUNT ON
                    DECLARE @userName AS nvarchar(max) = {0}
                    EXEC('
                    SELECT name FROM sys.server_principals where name = ['+ @userName +']
                    ')";
            return Convert.ToBoolean(context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(checkForUser, userName));
        }
```

However when I call this method I get an exception that the column (being whatever username was passed in) is invalid

```
$exception  {"Invalid column name 'viewer2'."}  System.Exception {System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException}
```

Any ideas as to what is causing this and is there a better way to check to see if a login exists within a sql db from code?

Cheers

Comment: I'm not sure if I'd be ok with the idea of having my user's account id's tied directly to my database like this. Is this like an internal dev tool?

Comment: may I ask why you are doing the stored proc this way opposed to adding it on the Server..? also what happens when you run this manually..?

Comment: Open SQL Server profiler and take a look what is sent to DB. This way you will know how to debug those things in future. You can than copy/paste the sent statement to SQL Management Studio and play until you see what was the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `'` instead of `[]` around your value. Otherwise, SQL server treat it as a column name.

```
string checkForUser =
    @" SET NOCOUNT ON
        DECLARE @userName AS nvarchar(max) = {0}
        EXEC('
        SELECT name FROM sys.server_principals where name = ''' + @userName +'''
        ')";
```

Comment: Where do you see SQL Injection here ? But you can remove + before and after @userName I think.

Comment: @PetarRepac What will happen, when `userName` will be set as e.g. `' OR 1 = 1 OR '' = '`?

Comment: Nothing. You pass this value as parameter, not with string concatenation.

Comment: Right ... sorry for false alarm :)

Comment: But there is a problem. It's DDL and you cannot use parameters there.

Comment: So, wrap @userName in QUOTENAME http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx and it will be better.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek I get the error when using the \ slash $exception {"Incorrect syntax near '\\'."} System.Exception {System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException}

Comment: IIRC escaping single quotes in tsql is made by doubling them. `where name = ''' + @userName + '''` should work better

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

```
protected static bool CheckForExistingUser(DbContext context, string userName)
        {
            return Convert.ToBoolean(context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SELECT name FROM sys.server_principals where name = {0}", userName));
        }
```

count will return a 0 or a 1 depending on whether the username exists satisfying the bool conversion... also removed all the trim in your code.  If it doesn't work let me know.

Comment: Personally though, the way I would write it is I would try to authenticate using that user to check whether they exist and then do something if it fails.

Comment: Ouch, SQL injection! Parametrize that query.

Comment: I don't think this would work, since `Database.ExecuteSqlCommand` is returning the query execution result (affected rows in this case, I think), not the count value.

Comment: @PHeiberg you're right on both counts, didn't notice the return type of executesqlcommand... seems like the wrong object to use here, but I don't know entity that well.  Also, parametrized.  I try to stay as close to the original code as possible typically though.

Answer (score 0):

As @MarcinJuraszek has answered, you can't have '[' around your string parameters. They have to have single quotes or be quoted automatically if sent as parameters.

Since it looks like you're using Entity Framework, I think you can make it more readable by executing a simpler query. In .NET Framework 4.0 and above you could do something like this:

```
string checkForUser = "SELECT count(1) FROM sys.server_principals where name = {0}";
return context.ExecuteStoreQuery<int>(checkForUser, userName).First() > 0;
```